# CSS Nav Bar Not Floating Right

Tags: html, css, alignment

I need the last tab (About) to float to the right and the others to the left. It all floats left.

```
<div class="nav">
    <ul>
    <li><a href="/ghaines1/">HOME</a></li>
    <li><a href="/ghaines1/cosc231/">COSC 231</a></li>
    <li><a href="/ghaines1/cosc231/8ball.html">MAGIC 8 BALL</a></li>
    <li><a href="/ghaines1/cosc231/proj4.html" id="aboutRight">ABOUT</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

a {
color:#b7b7b7;
text-decoration:none;
}

body {
background-color:#0d0d0d;
font-family:Tahoma;
color:#ffffff;
text-align:center;
margin:0;
}

#lines {
line-height:.3px;
}

hr {
width:30%;
}

#page {
text-align:left;
}

div {
margin:0 auto;
text-align:center;
}

img {
width:50%;
border:1px solid white;
}

.nav {
overflow: hidden;
position: fixed;
top: 0;
width: 100%;
}

.nav div {
width:100%;
position: fixed;
}

.nav ul {
 list-style-type: none;
 width:100%;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 overflow: hidden;
 background-color: #dbdbdb;
 }

.nav li {
 float: left;
 }

 .nav li a {
 color: white;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
   -o-transition:.25s;
  -ms-transition:.25s;
  -moz-transition:.25s;
  -webkit-transition:.25s;
   transition:.25s;
  }

 .nav li a:hover {
  background-color: #efefef;
 }

.aboutRight {
position: fixed;
float: right;
left: 100px;
}
```

Comment: Don't add garbage to your question. This attracted a red flag (spam/rude/abusive), and could have easily earned a serious penalty for your account. I've edited it out this time. The quality filter is there for a reason. You'd do better to listen to its advice and improve the amount of context/detail in your question, rather than adding rambling nonsense.

Answer (score 0):

First of all have style for class aboutRight `.aboutRight` and your link has ID `<li><a href="/ghaines1/cosc231/proj4.html" id="aboutRight">ABOUT</a></li>`. Rewrite id into class as it's a bad practice to use IDs for styling.

Second, you don't need `position:fixed;` in this style, it won't take space in a parent container, you need this link to be in a same position as other links.

Third, you should apply that class not to the `<a>` tag, but to the `<li>` element, because you want to float right `<li>` inside of `<ul>`, not `<a>` inside of `<li>`

And lastly, since you have this rule `.nav li { float: left; }` and want to override it for a certain li, you should write more specific selector, not just a class, e.g. `nav li.aboutRight`

I created a snippet for you with working code.

```css
a {
color:#b7b7b7;
text-decoration:none;
}

body {
background-color:#0d0d0d;
font-family:Tahoma;
color:#ffffff;
text-align:center;
margin:0;
}

#lines {
line-height:.3px;
}

hr {
width:30%;
}

#page {
text-align:left;
}

div {
margin:0 auto;
text-align:center;
}

img {
width:50%;
border:1px solid white;
}

.nav {
overflow: hidden;
position: fixed;
top: 0;
width: 100%;
}

.nav div {
width:100%;
position: fixed;
}

.nav ul {
 list-style-type: none;
 width:100%;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 overflow: hidden;
 background-color: #dbdbdb;
 }

.nav li {
 float: left;
 }

 .nav li a {
 color: white;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
   -o-transition:.25s;
  -ms-transition:.25s;
  -moz-transition:.25s;
  -webkit-transition:.25s;
   transition:.25s;
  }

 .nav li a:hover {
  background-color: #efefef;
 }

.nav li.aboutRight {
float: right;
left: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav">
    <ul>
    <li><a href="/ghaines1/">HOME</a></li>
    <li><a href="/ghaines1/cosc231/">COSC 231</a></li>
    <li><a href="/ghaines1/cosc231/8ball.html">MAGIC 8 BALL</a></li>
    <li class="aboutRight"><a href="/ghaines1/cosc231/proj4.html" id="aboutRight">ABOUT</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```